# how the value incresed without increasing in the this php code

Tags: php

```
<?php

function doSomething( &$arg ){
    $return = $arg;
    $arg += 1;
    return $return;
}

$a = 3;
$b = doSomething( $a );

echo $a.'  ';
echo $b;
?>
```

I know the answer a=4 and b=3 I understand how b= 3 but how come value of the a increased

Comment: Because you passed the argument by reference? (`&$arg`)

Answer (score 3):

The `&` operator tells PHP not to copy the variable when passing it to the function. Instead, a reference to the variable is passed into the function, thus the function modifies the original variable instead of a copy.

Therefore `$arg += 1;` will increase `$a`